# jQuery/javascript stop working after a remote call

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a page with a set of comments on an article and a jquery code that lets me edit a comment when i click on it:

comments.js.coffee

```
$ ->
  $(".comment").click ->
    html = '''
              <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/comment?id=''' + $(this).data('value') + '''" data-remote="true" id="updt_comment_form" method="post">
              <textarea name="content"> ''' + $(this).children('p').text()+ ''' </textarea>
              <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Save">
              </form>
           '''
    $(this).hide()
    $(html).insertAfter($(this))
```

When i submit this form (remotely), the following is rendered:
comments/update.js.erb

```
$('#comments').replaceWith('<%=  escape_javascript(render("comments", :layout => false)) %>');
$('#fresh_comment').show();
$('#fresh_comment').effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
```

After i submit this form, the jquery code in comments.js.coffee stops working. The next time i click in a comment, i won't be able to edit it, unless i reload the page (which defeats the purpose of using ajax).

Is this normal? Am i doing something wrong?

The only solution i can think of is resetting the jquery trigger in update.js.erb to make it work again... but that doesn't seem right.

I don't see why ANY of my jquery code stops working after executing ANY remote call.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the arrow do? `$(".comment").click ->` never seen it. Just curious. And I also find `'''` three quotes a bit strange

Comment: thats coffeescript, it's the same as $(".comment").click( function() { ...

Comment: strings between ''' indicate that their indentation and format are to be preserved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delegate the click handler to a container element, e.g.:

```
$("#comment").parent().delegate(".comment", "click", function() {
    // handler code
});
```

When you replace your `.comment`s via `.replaceWith` the original click handlers are no longer present. Event delegation means that attached handlers will always work since the handler is bound to a container element, which is not replaced.

Reference:

- http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Note: You can also use [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) for this, but `.delegate` has several advantages over it.

```
$(".comment").live("click", function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: Ah i see! So the bind between the handler and the dom element disappears when the element is replaced! That makes sense... The "#comments" div is replaced as well during the ajax call though. Should i use the following instead? $("body").delegate(".comment", ...

Comment: @dcastro - I just edited my answer. I think `$("#comment").parent().delegate(..` should suffice, however, what you suggested would definitely do the trick.

Comment: I tried as you suggested, it worked wonders! $ ->
  $("#comments").parent().delegate ".comment", "click", ->